how can i send query string through react to the backend
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Form, Row, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const FilterComponent = ({  categories, brands }) => {
    const { keyword} = useParams();

  const [category, setCategory] = useState(null);
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState(null);
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const param1 = params.get("category");
    const param2 = params.get("brand");
    const param3 = params.get("rating");
   

    // Only update state if the parameters are not null
    if (param1 !== null) {
      setCategory(param1);
    }
    if (param2 !== null) {
      setBrand(param2);
    }
    if (param3 !== null) {
      setRating(param3);
    }
    

    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);
    console.log(param3);
    console.log(category);
    console.log(brand);
    console.log(rating);
  }, [category, brand, rating, keyword, navigate ]);

  const handleCategoryChange = (event) => {
    const selectedCategory = event.target.value;
    setCategory(selectedCategory);
    console.log('category selected 1:', selectedCategory);
    if (selectedCategory){
        console.log('category selected 2:', selectedCategory);
        console.log('URL Parameters:', keyword);
        console.log(category)
        navigate(`/search/${keyword}/filter?category=${selectedCategory}&brand=${brand}&rating=${rating}`);  
    }
};

  const handleBrandChange = (event) => {
    const selectedBrand = event.target.value;
    setBrand(selectedBrand);
    if (selectedBrand){
        navigate(`/search/${keyword}/filter?category=${category}&brand=${selectedBrand}&rating=${rating}`);  
    }
  };

  const handleRatingChange = (event) => {
    const selectedRating = Number(event.target.value);
    setRating(selectedRating);
    if (selectedRating){
        navigate(`/search/${keyword}/filter?category=${category}&brand=${brand}&rating=${selectedRating}`);  
    }
  };

  const handleClearFilters = () => {
    setCategory("");
    setBrand("");
    setRating("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Filter By</h2>
      <Form>
        <Row className="d-flex flex-column ">
          <Col>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClearFilters}>
              Clear Filters
            </Button>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form.Group controlId="category">
              <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                as="select"
                value={category}
                onChange={handleCategoryChange}
              >
                <option value="">All Categories</option>
                {categories.map((category, index) => (
                  <option key={index} value={category}>
                    {category}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form.Group controlId="brand">
              <Form.Label>Brand</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                as="select"
                value={brand}
                onChange={handleBrandChange}
              >
                <option value="">All Brands</option>
                {brands.map((brand, index) => (
                  <option key={index} value={brand}>
                    {brand}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form.Group controlId="rating">
              <Form.Label>Rating</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                as="select"
                value={rating}
                onChange={handleRatingChange}
              >
                <option value="">All Ratings</option>
                {[...Array(5)].map((_, index) => (
                  <option key={index + 1} value={index + 1}>
                    {index + 1} Stars
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FilterComponent;



The query
getProducts: builder.query({
      query: ({ keyword, pageNumber, category, brand, rating}) => ({
        url: PRODUCTS_URL,
        params: {
          keyword,
          pageNumber,
          category, 
          brand,
          rating,
        },
      }),
      providesTags: ["Products"],
      keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
    }),

Front end routing
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route index={true} path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
      <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<HomeScreen />} />
      <Route path="/search/:keyword/filter" element={<HomeScreen />} />
)
)

In the backend i tried to console the req.query it is showing undefined undefined undefined
// @desc    Fetch all products
// @route   GET /api/products
// @access  Public
const getProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 
 
  const { category, brand, rating } = req.query; // Get the filter parameters from the query string
  console.log(category, brand, rating);

im getting  undefined undefined undefined  why?
suppose if selected
"electronics" as category
"apple" as brand
"4 star" as rating
I'm expecting in the backend
electronics apple 4 star
but what im actually getting
undefined undefined undefined
and "keyword" is successfully is getting in the backend
i dont understand why it is not getting into the backend controller
is there anyone to solve my doubt  ???

Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve]. Where is the getProducts endpoint invoked? Can you share the complete RTKQuery code so we can see your base query function to see how params is handled? What you have looks fine if you are using all the default functionality. Otherwise we'll need more complete debugging details. What does the out-going request look like? Does it have the correct query param values?

I'm pretty sure the issue is related to you setting the values as parameters and not in the query. In the back-end you are reading the query.
I believe moving the variables from params to query should fix the issue. However, it depends on the string stored in PRODUCTS_URL. Assuming PRODUCTS_URL is something inline of /api/products/{keyword}, following code snippet should fix the issue:
getProducts: builder.query({
      query: ({ keyword, pageNumber, category, brand, rating}) => ({
        url: `${PRODUCTS_URL}?category=${category}&brand=${brand}&rating=${rating}`,
        params: {
          keyword,
          pageNumber,
        },
      }),
      providesTags: ["Products"],
      keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
    }),

